# How can I change my color scheme for highlighting markdown text in rich (python)

Tags: python, markdown, color-scheme, rich

I am using the [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module to enable markdown support in the terminal. However, I am using a light-themed terminal and the default colors of rich markdown highlighting look borderline unreadable. So how would I go about changing the color scheme used by `rich.Markdown`?

[image: The code highlighting is almost unreadable]

The text above is the following:

> To use `rich`, we first import
>
> ```
> from rich.console import Console
> from rich.markdown import Markdown
> ```
>
> and then we can write
>
> ```
> console.print(Markdown(msg))
> ```

Note that using a dark-themed terminal works great with the default color scheme.

I looked through the docs of `rich`, in particular [Styles](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/style.html), [Highlights](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/highlighting.html) and [Markdown](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/markdown.html). However none of them seem to be able to answer my question of how I could support light theme (i.e. change to a custom color scheme for markdown).

You can create custom themes as shown in [Style Themes](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/style.html#style-themes), however those seem to only apply if you print to the console manually (and not if you use markdown).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/markdown.html?highlight=monokai#rich.markdown.Markdown), `Markdown` has a `code_theme` argument, which works for me:

```py
from rich.markdown import Markdown

console.print(Markdown(msg))

console.print(Markdown(msg, code_theme="manni"))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVMVX.png)